# How to customize tooltip for forceDirectedGraph in angular nvd3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am using the force directed graph in angular nv3d. I would like to customize the text color on the nodes as well as modify the tool tip. Ive also been trying to figure out how to force the nodes to be more sparse. Here is my chart object:

```
chart: {
      type: 'forceDirectedGraph',
      height: 450,
      color: function(d) {
        return color(d.Name);
      },
      tooltipContent: function (key) {
        return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
      },
      margin: {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
      nodeExtras: function(node) {
        node && node
          .append('text')
          .attr('dx', 15)
          .attr('dy', '.35em')
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.Name;
          })
          .style('font-size', '25px'); 
      },
    },
  };
```

As you can see, I tried adding the tooltipContent property to the chart object to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To customize the tool tip do the following

```
    chart: {
        type: 'forceDirectedGraph',
        ... /* All properties */
        height : 400,
        tooltip : { 
          contentGenerator : function (obj) { return "<div> **custom formating** </div>"}              
        }
    }
```